# Unexpected identifier - const

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm learning node.js and I have problem in example:

```
"use strict";

// Create a new globetrotter!
const globetrotter = {
    // Language spoken in the country our globetrotter is currently in
    const current_lang = undefined,

    // Number of countries our globetrotter has travelled to
    let countries = 0,

    // See how many countries we've travelled to
    get countryCount () {
        return this.countries;
    }, 

    // Reset current language whenever our globe trotter flies somewhere new
    set languages (language) {
        // Increment number of coutnries our globetrotter has travelled to
        countries += 1;

        // Reset current language
        this.current_lang = language; 
    };
};

globetrotter.language = 'Japanese';
globetrotter.countryCount; // 1

globetrotter.language = 'Spanish';
globetrotter.countryCount; // 2
```

This return me error:

```
index.js:6
    const current_lang = undefined,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Why and how can I resolve this error?

I have node.js in version 8.1.0.

Comment: It should be `current_lang: undefined`. Take a look at how [objects work in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining variables inside of an object literal, this is not correct javascript syntax for an object. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Hello. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)